# Distance Formula with random integers. Output not being produced

Tags: java

So, what I'm trying to do is calculate the distance between two points. I am given the seed and the number of simulations to run. My code runs, but doesn't work? The random generator wont generate numbers and add them to the array. I am seeding the random generator with **r**, and using **n** to run the simulations.

edit: The program gets stuck in a loop after I enter the input through the console It gets stuck at line `X1[i] = rand.nextInt(1000);`.

Example Input

2               --- t (number of paris to be tested)

12087 400       --- r, n (r = number to seed variable with,n = number of times to run rand)

7418 978        --- r, n (Second r and n)

Example output for example input --- (this is from the book)

553.994
525.789

With these numbers we use the random generator to produce X1, X2, Y1, Y2. These numbers will be the ones used for distance calculation.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Distance {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double distance = 0; // initiates all numbers needed and sets to 0)
        int r[] = new int[10];
        int n[] = new int[10];
        int X1[] = new int[10]; // Array initiations
        int X2[] = new int[10];
        int Y1[] = new int[10];
        int Y2[] = new int[10];

        Scanner q = new Scanner(System.in);

        int t = q.nextInt(); // Scans in t (Number of lines to follow)

        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
            r[i] = q.nextInt(); // Scans in r (Number of Random Objects)
            n[i] = q.nextInt(); // Scans in n (Number of Simulations)
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n[i]; i++) {
            Random rand = new Random(r[i]);
            X1[i] = rand.nextInt(n[i]); // fills index(s) i with Random number
                                        // in X1 values
            X2[i] = rand.nextInt(n[i]); // fills index(s) i with Random number
                                        // in X2 values
            Y1[i] = rand.nextInt(n[i]); // fills index(s) i with Random number
                                        // in Y1 values
            Y2[i] = rand.nextInt(n[i]); // fills index(s) i with Random number
                                        // in Y2 values

            distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((X2[i] - X1[i]), 2)
                    + Math.pow((Y2[i] - Y1[i]), 2));
        }
        System.out.println(distance);
    }
}
```

Comment: No. I don't have any ideas. Why don't you start by posting the specific problem you encountered?

Comment: "doesn't work" is very vague

Comment: @DavidWallace, the t is there to tell the program how many pairs of numbers to calculate the distance for.

Comment: You shouldn't keep changing the question once people start commenting and answering.  It makes a mockery of all the comments and answers.  Nobody can quite tell which version of the question anybody is answering or commenting on, and nothing makes sense.  It makes the question, all the answers, and all the comments completely useless to any future users of the site.  DON'T DO THIS.  I have voted to close the question for this reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second loop you had 0 is less than t so the loop control variable wasn't doing anything. 
You need to change it to i is less than t so the loop will end when i gets to t.

This solves your infinite loop problem, but i'm unsure if your program is working. 
In this second loop you are replacing r and n each time so there is no purpose of the loop because r and n will only store the last input.

Use the following code to fix this method

```
        for(int i = 0; i<t; i++) {
        r = q.nextInt();            //Scans in r  (Number of Random Objects)
        n = q.nextInt();            //Scans in n  (Number of Simulations)
    }
```

If i understand your question correctly, i think you are trying to use a different r and n for each pair. To accomplish this i would use an array to store all the different r and n values. Your print statement was also outside of the last for loop so you would only see the last pair's result.

```
import java.util.*;
```

public class help {

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    double distance = 0;            //initiates all numbers needed and sets to 0)
    int r[];
    int n[];
    int X1[];
    int X2[];
    int Y1[];
    int Y2[];

    Scanner q = new Scanner (System.in);

    int t = q.nextInt();            //Scans in t (Number of lines to follow)

    r = new int[t];
    n = new int[t];
    X1 = new int[t];
    X2 = new int[t];
    Y1 = new int[t];
    Y2 = new int[t];

    for(int i = 0; i<t; i++) {
        r[i] = q.nextInt();            //Scans in r  (Number of Random Objects)
        n[i] = q.nextInt();            //Scans in n  (Number of Simulations)
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {
        Random rand = new Random (r[i]);
        X1[i] = rand.nextInt(n[i]);      // fills index(s) i with Random number in X1 values
        X2[i] = rand.nextInt(n[i]);      // fills index(s) i with Random number in X2 values
        Y1[i] = rand.nextInt(n[i]);      // fills index(s) i with Random number in Y1 values
        Y2[i] = rand.nextInt(n[i]);      // fills index(s) i with Random number  in Y2 values

        distance = Math.sqrt( Math.pow((X2 [i] - X1 [i] ), 2) + Math.pow((Y2 [i] - Y1 [i] ), 2) );
        System.out.println(distance);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: @Ghandi Ahh good eye, thanks bro. I fixed that, but during the debugg console I get an error on the random generation portion. of the code. It halts on the line `X1[i] = rand.nextInt(n);`

Comment: @f6e9a my code works without any errors. Do you have any test input/output? What kind of results are you looking for? You arnt entering two points, so what are you finding the distance between?

Comment: @f6e9a Edit your original code because the original code ha 1000 instead of n. We need to see what you're working with to find the problem.

Comment: I edited my answer to give your solution. Is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading in a variable, **t**, to tell you how many extra variables to expect, you could do something like the following:

```
System.out.println("How many random objects?");
r = q.nextInt(); // Scans in r (Number of Random Objects)

System.out.println("How many simulations?");
n = q.nextInt(); // Scans in n (Number of Simulations)
```

This will let you see what is happening in each step, if something goes wrong, and is simply clearer. In any case, you should prompt the user of the program when you want them to input anything.

In addition, the first for loop is needs to look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        r = q.nextInt(); // Scans in r (Number of Random Objects)
        n = q.nextInt(); // Scans in n (Number of Simulations)
    }
```

Or else your loop will continue forever. This is because the second condition "0 < t" is *always* true when t is bigger than 0. So each time the loop starts over it will think it's good to go, and then never stop.

That same loop also doesn't make sense because you only need to read in **r** and **n** once, but this setup will have you read them in **t** times. In short, this loop is unnecessary.

With the second loop, if it is still not performing as you want, you should insert some informal debug statements such as this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        // If you want to make it clearer to read
        System.out.println("-------------------");
        System.out.println("i: " + i + ", n: " + n);

        Random rand = new Random(r);
        X1[i] = rand.nextInt(1000); // fills index(s) i with Random number
                                    // in X1 values

        System.out.println("X1[" + i + "]: " + X1[i]);

        X2[i] = rand.nextInt(1000); // fills index(s) i with Random number
                                    // in X2 values

        System.out.println("X2[" + i + "]: " + X2[i]);

        Y1[i] = rand.nextInt(1000); // fills index(s) i with Random number
                                    // in Y1 values

        System.out.println("Y1[" + i + "]: " + Y1[i]);

        Y2[i] = rand.nextInt(1000); // fills index(s) i with Random number
                                    // in Y2 values

        System.out.println("Y2[" + i + "]: " + Y2[i]);

        distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((X2[i] - X1[i]), 2)
                + Math.pow((Y2[i] - Y1[i]), 2));

        System.out.println("distance: " + distance);

        // If you want to make it clearer to read
        System.out.println("-------------------");

    }
```

So that when you run your program you can easily see what is happening each loop. This should point out where it is off, if at all.

One final thing here is that you are likely to encounter and [IndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html) in your second loop because you are going until i < n, but you declare each array to be of size "10". So if at any point n >= 10, your loop will break and give you that exception because X1[10] doesn't exist.

If you want to keep this structure, you can instead read in **n** before initializing the arrays, then initialize them with the **n** you read in. Like this:

```
System.out.println("How many random objects?");
    r = q.nextInt(); // Scans in r (Number of Random Objects)

    System.out.println("How many simulations?");
    n = q.nextInt(); // Scans in n (Number of Simulations)

    int X1[] = new int[n]; // Array initiations
    int X2[] = new int[n];
    int Y1[] = new int[n];
    int Y2[] = new int[n];
```

edit: Update based on OP update.

If you want to randomize the seed each time, you need to combine the second loop with the seed input. Full main method listed:

```
public void main() {

    double distance = 0; // initiates all numbers needed and sets to 0)
    int r = 0;
    int n = 0;

    Scanner q = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How many simulations?");
    n = q.nextInt(); // Scans in n (Number of Simulations)

    int X1[] = new int[n]; // Array initiations
    int X2[] = new int[n];
    int Y1[] = new int[n];
    int Y2[] = new int[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        System.out.println("How many random objects?");
        r = q.nextInt(); // Scans in r (Number of Random Objects)

        Random rand = new Random(r);
        X1[i] = rand.nextInt(1000); // fills index(s) i with Random number
                                    // in X1 values
        X2[i] = rand.nextInt(1000); // fills index(s) i with Random number
                                    // in X2 values
        Y1[i] = rand.nextInt(1000); // fills index(s) i with Random number
                                    // in Y1 values
        Y2[i] = rand.nextInt(1000); // fills index(s) i with Random number
                                    // in Y2 values
        distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((X2[i] - X1[i]), 2)
                + Math.pow((Y2[i] - Y1[i]), 2));

        System.out.println("distance: " + distance);
    }

    System.out.println(distance);

    q.close();
}
```

Comment: I made r and n arrays. The program runs now, I will try to work more at it and make it simpler to understand for you all and myself. I am still not getting the right answer from the example input, I am off by 40.

Comment: I updated the end of my post to help reseed each time. Making r and n arrays will complicate the input, rather than help the situation.  I may be misunderstanding the use of n. Also, note David's comment above. Please don't modify the original post over and over again.

Comment: Bryan Davis Thanks this solves my problem. I apologize @david Wallace, I will keep this in mind. I had no intentions of being confusing or counter productive.

Comment: I'm glad your problem was solved, but be sure to be precise as to what solved it so future viewers can identify their problem. Also, the accepted solution gets listed first, so also make sure to mark whichever answer has your fix as the accepted solution.